# NSString to char* with greek characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, encoding

I am using the following code to store the data of a string in a char*.

```
 NSString *hotelName = [components[2] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
hotelInfo->hotelName = malloc(sizeof(char) * hotelName.length + 1);
strncpy(hotelInfo->hotelName, [hotelName UTF8String], hotelName.length + 1); 
NSLog(@"HOTEL NAME: %s",hotelInfo->hotelName);
```

The problem is with the Greek characters that are printed strangely. I have also tried to use another encoding (e.g NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding -it crashes- )

I tried even that:

```
hotelInfo->hotelName = (const char *)[hotelName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

but it also produces strange characters.

What do I miss?

**EDIT:**
After some suggestions I tried the following:

```
if ([hotelName canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding]){
    const char *cHotelName = (const char *)[hotelName cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding];
    int bufSize = strlen(cHotelName) + 1;
    if (bufSize >0 ){
        hotelInfo->hotelName = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufSize);
        strncpy(hotelInfo->hotelName, [hotelName UTF8String], bufSize);
        NSLog(@"HOTEL NAME: %s",hotelInfo->hotelName);
    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"String cannot be encoded! Sorry! %@",hotelName);
    for (NSInteger charIdx=0; charIdx<hotelName.length; charIdx++){
        // Do something with character at index charIdx, for example:
        char x[hotelName.length];
        NSLog(@"%C", [hotelName characterAtIndex:charIdx]);
        x[charIdx] = [hotelName characterAtIndex:charIdx];
        NSLog(@"%s", x);
        if (charIdx == hotelName.length - 1)
            hotelInfo->hotelName = x;
    }
    NSLog(@"HOTEL NAME: %s",hotelInfo->hotelName);
}
```

But still nothing!

Comment: Have you tried using `characterAtIndex`? Objective-c has a ton of built in functions for lots of this, to the point where the whole thing can be done in about one line of code. It's weird seeing so much old C being used in an iOS app haha. (Dont get me wrong, I love C)

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Comment: @KrishnaCA I edited my question

Comment: @arniotaki, So, you want to read individual characters right. I believe that you can't read unicodes in the form of `char`

Comment: @KrishnaCA No I don't need to read individual characters but I tried above suggestion with characterAtIndex to see if it solves the problem! But nothing

Comment: Do you need to convert a given `NSString` with unicode to `std::string` and vice-versa then? I believe you won't be able to convert an `NSString` with unicode to `std::string` with all characters intact. There's a thing called `std::wstring` for this task. May I know if that is your task?

Comment: I would like to pass an objective-C NSString variable to a C char* variable of a struct. I dont know about std::string and std::wstring

Comment: Aarg, I missed something. See my corrected answer below (you should also use `cHotelName` in the `strncpy`-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is not guaranteed that any `NSString` can be represented as a C character array (so-called *C-String*). The reason is that there is just a limited set of characters available. You should check if the string can be converted (by calling `canBeConvertedToEncoding:`).

Secondly, when using the `malloc` and `strncpy` functions, they rely on the length of the *C-String*, not on the length of the `NSString`. So you should first get the C-String from the NSString, then get it's length (`strlen`), and use this value to the function calls:

```
const char *cHotelName = (const char *)[hotelName cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding];
int bufSize = strlen(cHotelName) + 1;
hotelInfo->hotelName = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufSize);
strncpy(hotelInfo->hotelName, cHotelName, bufSize);
```

Comment: It seems to work for most of the characters but not for polytonics or those with apostrohes. Of course is always better than nothing

Comment: In that case, you could try different encodings (like Unicode). The only importance is that you always use the returned `const char *` for the `strlen`, `malloc` and `strncpy` functions, to prevent crashes.